# error sh: 1: R/rJava/java: Permission denied

Tags: r, jar

I made a abc.jar file with code

```
public class abc{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hi";
        System.out.println("The string is: " + str);
    }
}
```

and installed in R package "rJava" 
I triggered the jar file from R script with command

```
system("<relativePath>/java -jar abc.jar")
```

faced an error `sh: 1: <relativePath>/java: Permission denied`

please suggest me how to resolve this.

Comment: It looks like you have a permissions issue.   Usually, this is a system error, not `java` or `r`.  Please check your files and make sure your relative paths are correct

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will get back to Linux admin,  where as regarding the relative paths, R folder (holds all r library packages) and jar file both are under same home directory. I hope the problem may be permissions, not with relative path.